# Dynamic page title with suffix word using routing data angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, suffix

I am using angular 5 and facing a problem . I want to change my page title dynamic.Already i did that But i did't add suffix after page title. Suppose my page title Home and i want to add suffix as Home | My Title. Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code..

```
app.component.ts file

 // imported 

 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import {Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

 this._router.events
 .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
 .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
 .map((route) => {
   while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
            return route;
        })
 .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
 .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
 .subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));



my routing file

{
 path: '', 
 component: HomeComponentComponent, 
 pathMatch: 'full', 
 data: { title: 'Home' }  
},
```

dynamic page title works fine. I want add suffix after page title as Home | My title
Please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

`.subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));`

do

`` .subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(`${event['title']} | ${myTitle}`)); ``

or create your own `myTitleService` which wraps the angular title service so that when you do

`this.myTitleService.setTitle(event['title']));`

it will call

`` this.titleService.setTitle(`${title} | ${globalTitle}`); ``